# How to get listed in the share menu?

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm creating a messaging app and I would like to enable other apps to share text to my app via the **share menu** option.

How do I get my app listed in there?

This is the menu I would like to get listed in:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't automatically be added to the `UIActivityViewController` in other apps. The only things that appear on that "share menu" are a few predefined apps that Apple has added support for, as well as any other app specific activities an app decides to add.

You can setup your app to appear in a list of apps for opening a file but that is not the same as what you are asking for here.

Comment: A better answer is below

Answer (score 20):

In iOS 8, Apple has now enabled a way for you to add your application to a user's Share Sheet as one of many features of Extensibility, which aims to make your app available to the user even when closed.

[image]

You can read a lot more about share extensions [here](http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained), or go straight to [Apple's pre-release documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) to dive into the code.

---

**Update:** Above link of Apple documentation is not working, check here [App Extension Programming Guide: Share](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html)