# How to open ionic app from youtube

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

When you open your youtube app on an iOS-Device you got the option to share the video. If you click on share a new window will pop up with all the options like: messenger, whatsApp or Mail. Is it possible to add my own Ionic app to the window?

Usecase would be:
User looks for a youtube video using the youtube app. When he found the video he is looking for, he can share the video and parse the url/id to my app.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you can do that unless you are the dev of the youtube app ;) 
Jokes aside, you can check this answer which I think might solve your problem: [How to get listed in the share menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107446/how-to-get-listed-in-the-share-menu)

Other links that might be of interest:

1. [Social Sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/) native plugin for Ionic
2. [PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) documentation